# Mootools Slideshow2 and jQuery Conflict

Tags: jquery, mootools, slideshow

This works, (sorta) using the jQuery.noconflict, but then my super cool Mootools Slideshow2 http://code.google.com/p/slideshow/
goes a little whacky, especially in FF and IE 7. It does (kinda) work in Safari, so I have hope. (I'm forcing all my stuff into compatibility mode and I'm not even bothering with IE8.)

```
jQuery.noConflict(); jQuery(function($){ $(window).load(function(){$("#field").fadeIn(2000);});});
```

The test page:

http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/details/jmoo.html

It's supposed to be like this, but I want the whole page to fade in: 
http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/details/
(The thumbnails and main photos aren't synced--this is just a test page for now.)

I've got a lot going on this page:
Cufon, sIFR, (It'd be all Cufon, but you can't justify Cufon. I have sIFR slightly delayed in other fade-in pages I'm building so it will trigger--I can set that up later...)
Curvey Corners (I can't get PIE to fade in properly).
And the Mootools show, and I want the whole page to fade into view...

Any ideas? Or is Slideshow2 just to complex to mess with?

**How would I get this page to fade in with Mootools?**

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I know jQuery a little more than I know Mootools, the Slideshow2 stuff is very easy to implement and requires no understanding of Mootools...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is! This works--but I had to change (window).load to (document).ready otherwise the Mootools slideshow freaks out.

--One more thing:

I have sIFR on this page (it'd be all Cufon, but you can't justify Cufon) so I had to call the replace sIFR right after the CSS is changed to block, otherwise, the sIFR won't work. I Had to put the sIFR config code just like this and on the same page, it would not work with the config code in another directory where I usually have it.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){$("#field").fadeIn(2000);});
 sIFR.replace(test, {selector: '#bar',
          css: '.sIFR-root {letter-spacing: 0; leading: -2.5; background-color: #e6e6e6; color: #79868e; font-size: 12px; text-align: justify; } a { color: #555055; text-decoration: none;} a:hover { color: #79868e; text-decoration: none; }'
        }); });
```

Now I've got jQuery and Mootools happily running on the same page. Someday, I'll learn Mootools when I have the time; I think it'd be more elegant to have everything coming out of the same js library, but this works fine for now.